# AWS Lambda in VPC calling other AWS services with no corresponding endpoint type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, endpoint

I have a vue.js/aws-nodejs/mongodb-atlas website.

To lock things down better, I'm switching the mongodb-atlas database to VPC peering with lambda.  That works just fine.  But the other aws services now are giving me problems.  They tend to just hang and never return.

I understand that I should use vpc endpoints specific to the aws services to make them work, but they are not consistently working or do not exist.  Here's what I have:

- lambda -> aws secret manager using secretmanager endpoint: works fine
- lambda -> invoking other lamdas using lambda endpoint: works fine
- lambda -> s3 does not work with interface endpoint, but does work with gateway endpoint.
- lambda -> aws ses using smtp-email endpoint: hangs
- lambda -> aws cognito admin functions (such as adminCreateUser), cannot find a cognito endpoint type:  hangs

I have created a separate, non-vpc lambda that calls the SES api.  My vpc lambda invokes this non-vpc lambda with parameters to send email.

This does work, but seems kludgey.   My old non-vpc code worked fine.   Before calling ses or doing anything dangerous, I checked custom permissions in my database.  But this new non-vpc lambda does not have access to the database and therefore is missing this check close to the api call.  This non-vpc lambda feels like potential weapon of mass destruction.

Apparently, I could use a NAT gateway. But a NAT gateway is expensive, especially if I want redundancy.  And using the public internet defeats the purpose of using a vpc in the first place.

- Why is the smtp-email endpoint not working while secretmanager and lambda endpoints do work?
- How can I call cognito admin functions from a vpc-based lambda if there is no cognito endpoint type?
- If there is no available endpoint type for a specific aws service (such as cognito), does that mean a NAT gateway is required?
- Are lambda functions without an apig interface safe from being invoked by hackers over the internet?
- Is using a non-vpc lambda to access aws services from a vpc lambda actually a good idea?
- Should I just use a NAT gateway?

Comment: "lambda -> s3 does not work with interface endpoint, but does work with gateway endpoint."
For S3 interfaces, you'll need to specifically use the interface endpoint, but use a gateway since it's free.

Comment: Are you sending email via the send-email API or via SMTP?

Comment: Sending the email via the SES api.

Comment: Believe that [SES SMTP via VPC Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/) should work. Regarding "non-vpc lambda feels like potential weapon of mass destruction", why? The Lambda cannot be invoked without the relevant IAM permissions, presumably. On Cognito, there's currently no endpoint option here at all, so NAT or somehow proxying the requests would be needed.

Comment: @jarmod I tried following the SES SMTP via VPC Endpoint instructions, but I could not get it to work.  The instructions seem specific to EC2 rather than lambda.  The security group seems to require the exact IP address of the ec2 instance as best I can guess so does not work with lambda.   I tried using a CIDR like I did with secret manager endpoint, but could not get it to work.   In any case, I guess I'll use the lambda proxy method rather than the NAT gateway.  thanks.

Comment: For the "source" in security group rules where you want to allow the Lambda function, you should use the security group ID of the security group assigned to the Lambda function.

Comment: You'll have to have a NAT Gateway to access Cognito. I know that's not what you want to hear, but there is currently no other option.